# Scheduling module crash in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, schedule, multiprocess

I encountered this error while running the script on windows. However, the script was working well on linux environment and I can't understand the nature of the error. Here is the code and the console error.

```
import time
import schedule
import subprocess
import os
import multiprocessing


dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_phoenix=os.path.join(dir, 'sub','phoenix', 'automated_Phoenix.py')
path_singlephoenix=os.path.join(dir, 'sub','single_phoenix', 'automated_SinglePhoenix.py')
path_brc=os.path.join(dir, 'sub','brc', 'automated_BRC.py')
path_singlebrc=os.path.join(dir, 'sub','single_brc', 'automated_SingleBRC.py')
path_outperformance=os.path.join(dir, 'sub','outperformance', 'automated_Outperformance.py')
path_cpc=os.path.join(dir, 'sub','cpc', 'automated_CPC.py')


def autorun():
    print("I'm working...")
    def phoenix(file):
        subprocess.run(['python', path_phoenix])
    def singlephoenix(file):
        subprocess.run(['python', path_singlephoenix])
    def brc(file):
        subprocess.run(['python', path_brc])
    def singlebrc(file):
        subprocess.run(['python', path_singlebrc])
    def outperformance(file):
        subprocess.run(['python', path_outperformance])
    def cpc(file):
        subprocess.run(['python', path_cpc]) 


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        files = [path_phoenix, path_singlephoenix, path_brc, path_singlebrc, path_outperformance, path_cpc]
        for i in files:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=phoenix, args=(i,))
            q = multiprocessing.Process(target=brc, args=(i,))
            s = multiprocessing.Process(target=outperformance, args=(i,))
            t = multiprocessing.Process(target=cpc, args=(i,))
            u = multiprocessing.Process(target=singlephoenix, args=(i,))
            v = multiprocessing.Process(target=singlebrc, args=(i,))
            p.start()
            q.start()
            s.start()
            t.start()
            u.start()
            v.start()
            p.join()
            q.join()
            s.join()
            t.join()
            u.join()
            v.join()

schedule.every().day.at("01:09").do(autorun)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Do you know why do I have this error? Please help, thanks

Windows 10 Python 3.8.5

Comment: How are you  "encountered this error on windows while the script was running on linux"?

Comment: Sorry I edited my post, I did not express myself well !

Comment: Take those nested function definitions out of `autorun`.

Comment: (And while you're at it, stop having them ignore their arguments, and stop launching 36 processes when you probably only want 6.)

Comment: Ok thank you very much @user2357112supportsMonica ! But I don't really understand why you talk about 36 processes launched? I only want 6 process to lunch indeed.

Comment: You have a loop over a 6-item list. On each iteration, you launch 6 processes. That makes 36 processes total.

Comment: On Windows, the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is _very_ important and should enclose all code that will only be run by the main process. This is because the subprocess will `import` the main script each time one is run. Having it inside a function is a little strange…

Comment: Alright I got it. So if I delete the loops and args options this will be fine?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I deleted the loop and args but now my 6 process are not launching at the same time. They launch successively when the previous one is finished

Comment: error shows `"can't pickle local autorun.<locals>.phonenix"`. You should define functions `def phonenix()`, `def singlephoenix()`, etc. outside `autorun`

Comment: Don't post error diagnostics as screenshots. Post them as text, that can be searched and indexed.